# Complicated Query based on two tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables, one containing the access history from some applications and the other containing the users who perform those access.

```
ACCESS_HISTORY
WORKSPACE - APP_ID - APP_NAME   -  USERNAME

WS_1        1        APP_NAME      USER_1
WS_1        1        APP_NAME      USER_2
WS_2        1        APP_NAME      USER_3
WS_3        2        APP_NAME      USER_1

USERS
WORKSPACE - USERNAME - IS_ADMIN - IS_DEVELOPER
WS_1        USER_1      YES          NO
WS_1        USER_2      NO           YES
WS_2        USER_3      NO           NO
WS_3        USER_1      NO           YES
```

I want to perform a `SELECT` query to get the detailed access information for each application (`acc_general` is the number of access from users who are not admin or developer, `acc_adm` is the access from admin users, `acc_dev` is the access from dev users, and `acc_total` is the sum of general, adm and dev access):

```
WORKSPACE  APP_NAME  APP_ID  ACC_GENERAL  ACC_ADM  ACC_DEV  ACC_TOTAL
WS_1       APP_NAME  1       0            1        1        2
WS_2       APP_NAME  1       1            0        0        1
WS_3       APP_NAME  2       0            0        1        1
```

Note that:

- In the `access_history`, the access refers to the same application when the workspace and `app_id` are the same. Two applications may have the same ID but be on different workspaces.
- Each `USERNAME` refers to the same user, but a user may be an Admin or a Developer from `WS_1` and be just a simple user on another workspace.
- The real database contain many rows (**700k**+ on `ACCESS_HISTORY` and **5k** on `USERS`) and many other columns, but that's not important now.
- I am using Oracle Database.
- If someone want to please edit my question title to a more appropriated one (I could not think of a better one).

Comment: What does your current query look like? What part is giving you trouble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/810e5e/4)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE ACCESS_HISTORY AS 
          SELECT 'WS_1' AS WORKSPACE, 1 AS APP_ID, 'APP_NAME' AS APP_NAME, 'USER_1' AS USERNAME FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'WS_1' AS WORKSPACE, 1 AS APP_ID, 'APP_NAME' AS APP_NAME, 'USER_2' AS USERNAME FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'WS_2' AS WORKSPACE, 1 AS APP_ID, 'APP_NAME' AS APP_NAME, 'USER_3' AS USERNAME FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'WS_3' AS WORKSPACE, 2 AS APP_ID, 'APP_NAME' AS APP_NAME, 'USER_1' AS USERNAME FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE USERS AS 
          SELECT 'WS_1' AS WORKSPACE, 'USER_1' AS USERNAME, 'YES' AS IS_ADMIN, 'NO' AS IS_DEVELOPER FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'WS_1' AS WORKSPACE, 'USER_2' AS USERNAME, 'NO' AS IS_ADMIN, 'YES' AS IS_DEVELOPER FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'WS_2' AS WORKSPACE, 'USER_3' AS USERNAME, 'NO' AS IS_ADMIN, 'NO' AS IS_DEVELOPER FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'WS_3' AS WORKSPACE, 'USER_1' AS USERNAME, 'NO' AS IS_ADMIN, 'YES' AS IS_DEVELOPER FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT a.WORKSPACE,
       a.APP_NAME,
       a.APP_ID,
       COUNT( CASE WHEN u.IS_ADMIN <> 'YES' AND u.IS_DEVELOPER <> 'YES' THEN 1 END ) AS ACC_GENERAL,
       COUNT( CASE u.IS_ADMIN WHEN 'YES' THEN 1 END ) AS ACC_ADM,
       COUNT( CASE u.IS_DEVELOPER WHEN 'YES' THEN 1 END ) AS ACC_DEV,
       COUNT( 1 ) AS ACC_TOTAL
FROM   ACCESS_HISTORY a
       INNER JOIN
       USERS u
       ON (   a.WORKSPACE = u.WORKSPACE
          AND a.USERNAME  = u.USERNAME )
GROUP BY
       a.WORKSPACE,
       a.APP_NAME,
       a.APP_ID
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/810e5e/4/0)**:

```
| WORKSPACE | APP_NAME | APP_ID | ACC_GENERAL | ACC_ADM | ACC_DEV | ACC_TOTAL |
|-----------|----------|--------|-------------|---------|---------|-----------|
|      WS_1 | APP_NAME |      1 |           0 |       1 |       1 |         2 |
|      WS_2 | APP_NAME |      1 |           1 |       0 |       0 |         1 |
|      WS_3 | APP_NAME |      2 |           0 |       0 |       1 |         1 |
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
SELECT h.workspace, h.appid, h.appname, u.username, 
SUM(CASE WHEN u.is_admin=0 AND u.is_dev=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS acc_general,
SUM(CASE WHEN u.is_admin>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS acc_admin, 
SUM(CASE WHEN u.is_dev>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) acc_dev, COUNT(*) AS acc_total
FROM acc_history h LEFT JOIN users u 
ON h.worksapce=u.workspace AND h.username=u.workspace
GROUP BY h.workspace, h.appid, h.appname, u.username
```